# generating image features dataset in scikit-learn - csv file

Tags: image, dataset, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I extract 2 edge features (Hog feature and sobel operator) from a single image.

How can i create an image feature dataset in Scikit-learn python, like iris_dataset ? 
In the library there are csv files which represent datasets. A csv file containing only numbers. How were generate these numbers? feature extraction?

unfortunately i saw only a java tutorial here http://www.coccidia.icb.usp.br/coccimorph/tutorials/Tutorial-2-Creating-..., at 5 point talk about generating the training matrices (average and co-variance matrices)?
There is any function in Scikit who generate these training arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your data as a CSV file to load it as a dataset. scikit-learn models have a `fit` method that expects:

- as first argument that is a regular numpy array (or scipy.sparse matrices) with shape `(n_samples, n_features)` (most often with `dtype=numpy.float64`) to encode the features vector for each sample in the training set,
- and for supervised classification models, a second argument with shape `(n_samples,)` and `dtype=numpy.int32` to encode the class label assignments encoded as integer values for each sample of the training set.

If you don't know the basic numpy datastructure and what `shape` and `dtype` mean, I stongly advise you to have a look at a tutorial such as [SciPy Lecture Notes](http://scipy-lectures.github.com/).

**Edit**: If you really need to read / write numerical CSV to / from numpy arrays, you can use `numpy.loadtxt` / `numpy.savetxt`

Comment: yes, but, it's correct: i extract 100 numpy arrays from 100 hundred images and i make a 1 numpyarray composed by 100 numpy arrays?and put in  n_features spot?

Comment: and for samples what they mean (in tutorial: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html), an array of what? sorry for dummy questions but i do not figure out how worls this stuff!

Comment: For a supervised task (e.g. classification problem), you typically train the model by calling `model.fit(X, y)` where `X` is a 2 dimensional array `n_samples` rows (one for each instance or image to classify) and `n_features` columns, one for each "feature" or "attribute" that describe your instances / samples / objects / images / whatever and `y` is one dimensional array of `n_samples` integer values, that represent the class label assignments for each row in `X`. E.g. for a binary classification problem each element in y can be either `0` or `1` for instance.

Comment: By the way to concatenate several 1d arrays as rows of a 2D array you can use: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

Comment: i check hog feature array of a single image, has got that shape: (210, 203) i change it by ravel() making 1d array.                 I put in n_samples only 1 image in 2D array (shape: (210,203)). Obviously i got error:"X has 210 samples, but y has 42630.". i think i made two main errors: I put only an image in fit function and i have to put 210 samples and 210 features. it's correct? If it is, i think i have to lookin for how many 2d arrays hog feature i put (one 2d array for every image) in a 1d array?

Comment: `n_samples` is not a variable name for an array. It's a way to tell "number of samples". It's an integer. If you have 3 images with 1000 HOG features each, they `n_samples == 3`, `n_features == 1000` and `X` has shape `(n_samples, n_features) == (3, 1000)`. Please follow the tutorial I gave you or learn numpy elsewhere first.